# LinQ Group With Priority

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

First of all, my English is not the best but I'm trying my best.

Well, I just moved to EF and Linq and I'm learning it but I'm struggled in a  query (I don't mind about getting it either linq or EF). The point is I have these objects:

```
 public class ExchangeRate
{

    public int ExchangeRateID { get; set; }

    public string BaseCurrencyISO { get; set; }

    public string CurrencyISO { get; set; }

    public DateTime RateDate { get; set; }

    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }

}
```

So and example data could be:

```
1, "EUR", "USD", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "ECB"
1, "EUR", "AED", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "ECB"
1, "EUR", "USD", 01/01/2017, 1.24, "Bundesbank"
1, "EUR", "AED", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "Bundesbank"
1, "EUR", "ABC", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "Bundesbank"
1, "EUR", "ARS", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "ECB"
1, "EUR", "USD", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "OtherSource"
1, "EUR", "EZZ", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "Bundesbank"
1, "EUR", "DIN", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "Bundesbank"
1, "EUR", "BUM", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "OtherSource"
1, "EUR", "DIN", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "ECB"
```

What I need is to query this objects keeping just one record per BaseCurrencyISO, CurrencyISO and RateDate priorizing the Source Field in an arbitrary way. In this case it will be: ECB > Bundesbank > OtherSource.

So, the query should return:

```
1, "EUR", "USD", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "ECB"
1, "EUR", "AED", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "ECB"
1, "EUR", "USD", 01/01/2017, 1.24, "Bundesbank"
1, "EUR", "ABC", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "Bundesbank"
1, "EUR", "ARS", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "ECB"
1, "EUR", "EZZ", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "Bundesbank"
1, "EUR", "BUM", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "OtherSource"
1, "EUR", "DIN", 01/01/2018, 1.24, "ECB"
```

I'm totally lost on how to do it.

Any guidance or advise it's truthly apreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Do some research, show what you have tried and where you got stuck in a [mcve]. This is not a free code writing service. We can assist once we know where the problem lies. Not knowing how to do it is off-topic

Comment: How do we know that `ECB` is greater than others two `Source` ?

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir I believe that is just preference or requirement of the OP.  It can be easily implemented on the data once grouped.

Comment: @Nkosi, I think you missed the part where I say I'm beginning with linq and EF and I'm totally lost in this one. I could put what I've tried that is a wrong done groupby query but that would be no sense. Anyways, thanks for your support.

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir is arbitrary so it has to be hardcoded i guess, koryakinp gave the right answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that query will do the job:

```
exchangeRateList
    .GroupBy(q => new { q.BaseCurrencyISO, q.CurrencyISO, q.RateDate })
    .Select(q => q
        .OrderByDescending(w => w.Source == "ECB")
        .ThenByDescending(w => w.Source == "Bundesbank")
        .ThenByDescending(w => w.Source == "OtherSource")
        .FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Downvoter, what is wrong with my answer ?

Comment: It produces desired output.

Comment: I am wondering, too. It is exact answer.

Comment: Why did you use group by instead of group join when your result does not incorporate the key? Why have you added a redundant select instead of projecting in the first call? Why have you converted it to a list, forcing evaluation and preventing composition, when not requested? Why have you used method syntax when query expression syntax is so much more readable in this case?

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I will be glad if you post an alternative solution.

Comment: @koryakinp this post SAVED MY LIFE!!!! Thank you!